# Cleaned_data coming as empty data in django form?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a form field and it is a form.JsonField(). When I am submitting data,and logging the data received in the cleaned_data, it always outputs the empty data. Reason being, when I log the request.POST, I can see the incoming data is coming as list e.g `<Querydict:{"name":["test",'']`. When I pass request.POST to my form, I always get `self.cleaned_data.get("name")` as empty. It always gives me the last item from the list value.
Possible solution in my mind, is to manipulate the request.POST data before sending to form and then everything will work fine.
e.g

```
 update_request = request.POST.copy()
   updated_request['name'] = updated_request.getlist('name')[0]
```

Now, I can pass this to my form
e.g `form = MyForm(updated_request,instance=self.get_sample())`
Point is this seems more like a hack compared to a clean solution. Is there a more efficient way to do this instead of hacking all this in the views.

Comment: Why is the last one always an empty string? It looks like something is wrong with the HTML form with which you work

Comment: Can you share how you constructed the HTML form?